# showing page in iframe

Tags: html

Can we show  part of same  page in iframe that contain iframe?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063231/can-an-iframe-pop-up-a-lightbox-style-box/3063312#3063312

Answer (score 0):

yes - I am pretty sure you can - why not try it see. I am pretty sure it won't break anything.